# How would i get channel count of audio file without using decodeAudioData()?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, html5-audio, web-audio-api

So as you can see below, it looks like the only method i can think of to get the channel count of an audio file(including wav, mp3) is by using decodeAudioData(). However, i want to be able to get the channel count without decoding the whole audio file which uses alot of CPU (i think its CPU).

Is there any other method to achieve this? If not, is there a way of decoding only a section of the file?

Thanks in advance!

```
  audio_file.onchange = function() {

    let files = this.files;
    let file = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', file, true);
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.onload = () => {
        audioContext.decodeAudioData(xhr.response).then((buffer) => {
            CHANNEL_COUNT = buffer.numberOfChannels;
            if (CHANNEL_COUNT === 4){
                    document.querySelector('.status').innerHTML = 'FOA file detected';
                }
                else {
                    document.querySelector('.status').innerHTML = "Audio file with " + CHANNEL_COUNT + " channels detected";
                }

        });
    }

    xhr.send(null);

    audioElement.src = file;
    audioElement.load();

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The channel information is usually at the beginning of the encoded file, so you could just download the first few thousand bytes and use decodeAudioData on it.  However, I think many audio containers can support changing the number of channels in the middle of the file.  You'll lose that information, but then so would decodeAudioData.